# Test for equality between all members of list

Tags: r, list

What is the right syntax to check equality between all members of a list?  I found that

```
do.call(all.equal, list(1,2,3))
```

returns `TRUE`.

My hunch is that it is checking equality within elements of a list, not between.

Ideally the solution would ignore the name of the element, but not those of the element components.  For example, it should return TRUE given the input:

```
some_list <- list(foo = data.frame(a=1),
                  bar = data.frame(a=1))
```

But FALSE given the input:

```
some_other_list <- list(foo = data.frame(a=1),
                        bar = data.frame(x=1))
```

But I could live with a solution that was sensitive to the name of the element.

---

**Edit**:  Clearly I need to review `?funprog`.  As a follow-up to the <s>accepted</s> answer, it's worth noting the following behavior:

```
Reduce(all.equal, some_list)  # returns TRUE

Reduce(all.equal, some_other_list) #returns [1] "Names: 1 string mismatch"
```

And for:

```
yet_another_list <- list(foo = data.frame(a=1),
                        bar = data.frame(x=2))
Reduce(all.equal, yet_another_list)
# returns: [1] "Names: 1 string mismatch"     "Component 1: Mean relative difference: 1"
```

---

**Edit 2:** My example was inadequate, and `Reduce` doesn't work in the case of 3 or more elements:

```
some_fourth_list <- list(foo = data.frame(a=1),
                  bar = data.frame(a=1),
                  baz = data.frame(a=1))
Reduce(all.equal, some_fourth_list) # doesn't return TRUE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1)** IF the list has only two components as in the question then try this:

```
identical(some_list[[1]], some_list[[2]])
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** or for a general approach with any number of components try this:

```
all(sapply(some_list, identical, some_list[[1]]))
## [1] TRUE

L <- list(1, 2, 3)
all(sapply(L, identical, L[[1]]))
## [1] FALSE
```

**3) Reduce**  This is a bit verbose compared to the prior solution but since there was a discussion of `Reduce`, this is how it could be jmplemented:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) x && identical(y, some_list[[1]]), init = TRUE, some_list)
## [1] TRUE

Reduce(function(x, y) x && identical(y, L[[1]]), init = TRUE, L)
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: This works too, thanks.  But I do like that `Reduce(all.equal, the_list))` gives a little more information about mismatch.

Comment: `Reduce(all.equal, the_list)` doesn't work.  Try `Reduce(all.equal, list(1, 1, 1))`

Comment: That is really weird!

Comment: Realize that what `Reduce(all.equal, list(1, 1, 1))` means is `all.equal(all.equal(1, 1), 1)`.  The inner `all.equal` makes sense but the outer `all.equal` makes no sense at all since it is comparing the output of all.equal to a numeric.

Comment: Right -- and the only reason it worked is because my "minimum viable example" had two elements and so there was no outer `all.equal`

Comment: I think this answer could be trivially improved by `all(sapply(L[-1], identical, L[[1]]))` since we don't need to check self-equality

Comment: That would take less time (or maybe it wouldn't if the subsetting takes more time than the saved comparison) but it would be a bit uglier.

Comment: This has been really helpful.  When I have a really long list... I'm pretty sure that neither the loop nor the `Reduce` would stop at the first mismatch?  But checking for equality is pretty fast, so it's not a practical issue.

Comment: It will do a comparison for every component of the input list but I believe that internally the `all` will short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
identical(unlist(some_list), unlist(some_other_list))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not trying to test equality of two lists, rather the elements within a given list.